# How to get the value from URL in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, url-parameters

I have a URL with some GET parameters as follows:

https://khanhjs.web.app/js/rooms/edit_rooms.html?hotelId=2/rooms?id=1
I tried this method:

```
const UrlParam = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
hotelId = UrlParam.get('hotelId');
```

the result I get is :

```
2/rooms?id=1
```

The result I want to get for the ***hotelId*** variable is 2 and the variable ***id*** is 1.
I need to get the whole value of hotelId && id.

Comment: That is one poorly written url....

Comment: Query parameters are supposed to be separated with `&`.

Comment: The correct way to have multiple parameters would be `?hotelId=2&id=1`. There are JS libraries that will parse this for you.

Comment: See here: https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/

Answer (score -1):

Since your url does not conform very well to standard `search` value to be passed to `URLSearchParams`, just avoid it and parse the `search` portion as a string.

So, this is what you have to work with:

> ```
> ?hotelId=2/rooms?id=1
> ```

1. Substring after the question mark (`?`)
2. Split by forward-slash (`/`)
3. Now for each pair, replace the `s?i` with `I`.

   - This just converts anything like `rooms?id=` to `roomId`
4. You could optionally parse any number-like values into integers
5. Now convert the list of pairs to an object by calling `Object.fromEntries`

### Demo

```js
const url = 'https://khanhjs.web.app/js/rooms/edit_rooms.html?hotelId=2/rooms?id=1';

const extractParams = (...path) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(new URL(path).search
    .substring(1)
    .split('/')
    .map(pair =>
      (([key, value]) => [
        key.replace(/s\?i/, 'I'),
        (!isNaN(value) ? parseInt(value, 10) : value)
      ])
     (pair.split('='))));
  
  console.log(searchParams);
  
};

console.log(extractParams(url));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

#### Result

```json
{
  "hotelId": 2,
  "roomId": 1
}
```

### Recursion to the rescue!

Alternatively, you could try recursion, if the URL represents a nested structure.

```js
const url = 'https://khanhjs.web.app/js/rooms/edit_rooms.html?hotelId=2/rooms?id=1';

const extractParams = (...path) => parse(new URL(path).search, {});

const parse = (params, result) => {
  if (params == null) return result;
  const index = params.indexOf('/');
  let head, tail;
  if (index !== -1) {
    head = params.substring(0, index);
    tail = params.substring(index + 1);
  } else {
    head = params;
    tail = null;
  }
  const [ root, pair ] = head.split('?')
  const [ key, value ] = pair.split('=');
  if (root === '') {
    result = { ...result, [key]: value };
  } else {
    result[root] = { ...result[root], [key] : value };
  }
  return parse(tail, result);
};

console.log(extractParams(url));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

#### Result

```json
{
  "hotelId": "2",
  "rooms": {
    "id": "1"
  }
}
```